# ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-window-token/fesm2015/ngx-window-token.mjs. Can't import the named export 'InjectionToken' from non EcmaScript module

Tags: angular, build

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGENY.png)

Above project working fine on the local setup well. But when we host in any Linux server. it gives the above error.

Comment: Please don't share code as an image. Nobody wants to debug images.

Answer (score 5):

I've added that line to frontend/package.json

"ngx-window-token": "^5.0.0",

I've found the solution here:
https://github.com/juice-shop/juice-shop/commit/84b0d6e3a85bbd1ab34aebb32a511811100a41c0

That's works for me

Comment: ngx-window-token@6.0.0 need angular 13 to build?